# I can't color the volume line.What can I do?

Tags: pine-script

```
indicator(“My Script”)
plot(volume)
i_col=input.color(color.green,”Plot Color”)         
plot= close>open? color.green:close.red
```

Ternary operator does not work, does not color, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ternary operator to create your color variable. Then pass that variable as `color` argument to the `plot()` function.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
i_col = close > open ? color.green : color.red
plot(volume, color=i_col)
```

[image]

Kolay gelsin.